# Uso de Templates com PHP

Tags: php, template

**Salve!**
Tenho um sisteminha com template que montei em **PHP** representado pela seguinte estrutura:

```
require("header.php");
require("content.php");  //carregado dinamicamente via GET
require("footer");
```

Tudo funciona bem, mas tenho que administrar o **CSS** e **JS** de cada *content*.
Uma vez que o **CSS** esta inserido em *header.php* e o **JS** em footer.php, qual seria a melhor forma para inserir os arquivos específicos de cada *content*?
A intenção seria carregar os scripts referentes ao *content* específico, mas tenho problemas principalmente com **JS** quando tento inserí-los diretamente no *content*.
**Desde já agradeço a força!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

podes utilizar uma variavel!

```
//tens de declarar antes de chamar o arquivo content
$script = '<script type="text/javascript" src="source.js"></script>';
```

No arquivo **content.php**

```
[..]
 echo (isset($script)) ? $script : '';
[..]
```

se tiveres multiplos scripts podes usar um array

Comment: Eu estou atualmente utilizando uma solução parecida. Eu tenho que criar três arquivos com o mesmo nome, porém extensões diferentes (_content.php_, _content.js_, _content.css_). Minha dúvida é quanto a performance e segurança se ficam comprometidas.

Answer (score 1):

Se você recebe via get o parametro do content, tenta assim:

Supondo que você está redirecionando para uma página chamada **home**.
E você criou os arquivos `home.css`, `home.js`, `home.php`

**URL** será o parametro via get que você citou.

**NO HEADER**

```
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $_GET['url'];?>.css">
    </head>
```

**NO CONTENT**

```
<body> 
  require $_GET['url].'php';
</body>
```

**NO FOOTER**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $_GET['url'];?>.js"></script>
```

Comment: acredito que isto seja mau hábito

Comment: Na verdade, hoje ele está funcionando com um sistema semelhante a solução sugerida. Mas estava com dúvida se esta é a melhor solução em questão de segurança e performance.

Comment: eu acho que em performance é grave porque sempre que quiseres criar uma pagina teras de criar 3 arquivos home.css, home.js, home.php ?

Comment: Esta não é uma solução boa, mas referente a pergunta, é uma solução válida. Tudo varia de projeto para projeto. O correto seria um `css`, e os javascripts necessários.